# Deploying a Flask app on AWS apache2 using mod_wsgi (Internal Server Error)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy my flask blueprint app to apache2 using mod_wsgi virtual host and am stuck with the a number of errors.

**Errors:** when I load the EC2 Public DNS, it shows me an internal server error with the message - *The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.*
**This is how the apache2 error-log looks like:**

```
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.462363 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000] mod_wsgi (pid=130081): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/loginapp/project/app.wsgi'.
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.462425 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000] mod_wsgi (pid=130081): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/loginapp/project/app.wsgi'.
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.462891 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.462932 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000]   File "/var/www/html/loginapp/project/app.wsgi", line 11, in <module>
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.462939 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000]     from app import app as application
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.462948 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000]   File "/var/www/html/loginapp/project/app.py", line 2, in <module>
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.462953 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000]     from flask import Flask
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.462962 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000]   File "/home/ubuntu/mapmymoney/loginapp/auth/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.462966 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000]     from . import json as json
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.462974 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000]   File "/home/ubuntu/mapmymoney/loginapp/auth/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.462979 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000]     import uuid
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.462994 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000]   File "/home/ubuntu/mapmymoney/loginapp/auth/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uuid.py", line 138
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.463005 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000]     if not 0 <= time_low < 1<<32L:
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.463029 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000]                                 ^
[Thu Jun 10 18:54:17.463040 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 130081:tid 139934426003200] [remote 122.170.209.102:61000] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am able to run this code on ec2 through Flask's webserver using the commands

```
source auth/bin/activate
export FLASK_APP=project
flask run
```

Following is my app structure: inside /home/ubuntu/mapmymoney/loginapp, I have two folders:

- auth (this is the python3 virtual env, having bin, lib and all the site-packages)
- project(this has app.py, app.wsgi, main.py, auth.py, static folder, template folder..)

*Note: The virtual environment folder is also named auth. Just one of my mistakes. The auth.py file is different and contains routes.*

This is how my **app.py** looks like:

```
from logging import debug
from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL



db = MySQL()


app = Flask(__name__)

#config for aws production
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = '*****'
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = 3306
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'admin'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = '****'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'loginapp'

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '******'

db.init_app(app)

# blueprint for auth routes in our app
from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

# blueprint for non-auth parts of app
from .main import main as main_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

#return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run
```

And this is how the **app.wsgi** looks like:

```
activate_this = '/home/ubuntu/mapmymoney/loginapp/auth/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as f:
    exec(f.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/loginapp/project")
```

Have also made changes to the apache2 **000-default.conf** file as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        WSGIDaemonProcess project threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/loginapp/project/app.wsgi

        <Directory /var/www/html/loginapp/project>
                WSGIProcessGroup project
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

       
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Also took care to install modwsgi for python 3 dependency(I am running Python 3.8).

I am really confused with the errors as the app runs perfectly on the flask's inbuilt-webserver on my AWS.

Comment: You can see that it says syntax error `if not 0 <= time_low < 1<<32L:` fix this and it will work

Comment: Hey @charchit, thanks for the revert. That error is creeping in inside the uuid package file so haven't touched it. Also, the same works perfect when I launch it with flask's server. Can't really see the point of changing the package. I believe that I am somehow not able to get the virtual env running. 
Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/loginapp/project/app.wsgi'.

Comment: Finally got it to work. As mentioned by @charchit, it was the uuid package generating the problem. uuid now comes bundled with Python3 and mine was shadowing it. pip uninstall uuid worked.

Also, the typing package will pose problems when deploying. Uninstalling that will do the trick. Just so the comment helps someone.